# Doctrine2 and MongoDB - actual value is not fetched from database in long-polling loop

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, long-polling

We are implementing the long-polling in our Symfony application, so the controller1 updates  some member of the instance of the class User

```
     $dm = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getManager();
...
     $User->setSomeValue($value);
     $dm->persist($User);
     $dm->flush();
```

Another controller2 which contains long-polling loop first
fetches the $user and value from database then with some interval
does $dm->refresh($User) and pulls the value.

```
     $dm = $this->get('doctrine_mongodb')->getManager();
...
     $User=$userRepo->findOneBy(array('id' => $userId));
     $value = $User->getSomeValue();
...
      while(...){
        sleep(1);
        $iteration++;
        $dm->refresh($User);
        $value = $User->getSomeValue();
...
     }
```

If controller1 updates the value during the loop execution the old value is fetched by controller2 inside the loop but not an updated one.

What is the issue?

Comment: I think that you need to dettach the object in second controller, because of multiple EntityManagers

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the issue you're describing with the following CLI scripts. These are modeled after the `tools/sandbox/index.php` example (included in the ODM repository) and are being run from the same directory.

The first script, `poll.php`, refreshes a particular document once a second and prints some string field:

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/config.php';

$id = new MongoId('5432e4e6e84df199228b4567');
$repo = $dm->getRepository('Documents\User');
$user = $repo->findOneBy(['_id' => $id]);
$iteration = 0;
printf("%d: %s\n", $iteration, $user->getUsername());

poll: {
    sleep(1);
    $iteration++;
    $dm->refresh($user);
    printf("%d: %s\n", $iteration, $user->getUsername());
}

goto poll;
```

The second script, `modify.php`, changes the same document's field to a random string.

```
<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/config.php';

use Documents\User;

$id = new MongoId('5432e4e6e84df199228b4567');
$user = new User();
$user->setId($id);
$user->setUsername(md5(rand()));

$dm->persist($user);
$dm->flush();

printf("Changed username to: %s\n", $user->getUsername());
```

I made one small change to the `tools/sandbox/Documents/User.php` model and added a `setId()` method. This allows the `modify.php` script to do an upsert on the first run and create the document we'll later modify.

With these two files in place, I started things off by creating the document:

```
$ php modify.php 
Changed username to: 9bdfab05b06306e97d2f63c9bc0a34ef
```

I then started `poll.php` in a second terminal and proceeded to run `modify.php` a few times:

```
$ php poll.php 
0: 9bdfab05b06306e97d2f63c9bc0a34ef
1: 9bdfab05b06306e97d2f63c9bc0a34ef
2: 8420c8ef0ee7194624fead56585e8be5
3: 8420c8ef0ee7194624fead56585e8be5
4: bf2ec4bafae4cf47e3162ce857e861e7
5: bf2ec4bafae4cf47e3162ce857e861e7
6: bf2ec4bafae4cf47e3162ce857e861e7
7: 2051dd54bc2883f6c11e6c2bbfdfd13e
8: 2051dd54bc2883f6c11e6c2bbfdfd13e
9: 2051dd54bc2883f6c11e6c2bbfdfd13e
```

If you trace the calls within `DocumentManager::refresh()`, you'll see that it ultimately calls [`DocumentPersister::refresh()`](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/Persisters/DocumentPersister.php#L414), which very simply queries for the raw document data via the `Doctrine\MongoDB\Collection` wrapper class, hydrates that data, and resets the original document data (used for changeset computation). Debugging the raw data (from MongoDB) that gets hydrated and re-assigned to the snapshot would be a good place to start if you're not seeing the new data.